# Amazon EMR Clusters stuck on starting state

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm creating clusters on AWS EMR (with Console and SDK). But these clusters always remain "starting" state and never start. Why can this happen and how can I solve it? Thanks.

**bootstrap-actions log:**
INFO i-062fab1a95f485684: new instance started
ERROR i-062fab1a95f485684: failed to start. bootstrap action 1 failed with non-zero exit code.

**My codes:**

```
val emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard()
  .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCred))
  .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1)
  .build()

val stepFactory = new StepFactory();
val enabledebugging = new StepConfig()
  .withName("Enable debugging")
  .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
  .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep())

val spark = new Application().withName("Spark")
val hive = new Application().withName("Hive")
val ganglia = new Application().withName("Ganglia")
val zeppelin = new Application().withName("Zeppelin")

val request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
  .withName("Spark Cluster")
  .withReleaseLabel("emr-5.20.0")
  .withSteps(enabledebugging)
  .withApplications(spark)
  .withLogUri("s3://my-logs")
  .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
  .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
  .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
    .withEc2SubnetId("subnet-xxxxx")
    .withEc2KeyName("ec2test")
    .withInstanceCount(3)
    .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(true)
    .withMasterInstanceType("m5.xlarge")
    .withSlaveInstanceType("m5.xlarge")
  );
val result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
System.out.println("The cluster ID is " + result.toString());
```

Comment: Post the configuration used to create the EMR cluster

Comment: I added scala codes that I used to create cluster

Comment: Have you tried debugging by removing bits until it works? For example, if you remove the `RunJobFlowRequest`, does it work?

Comment: Please first run " emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder" part only to have an EMR cluster up and running. Make sure the logs are saved to S3 (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-debugging.html#emr-plan-debugging-logs-archive). Without it, debugging bootstrap issues would be too hard. Make sure enough disk spaces are attached. If the disk space is not enough to install packages, EMR will shutdown.

Comment: Once you start getting the logs in S3, look into the master node bootstrap logs to make sure all the steps succeeded. Until bootstrap goes through, keep configuration simple, put all the nodes in public subnet with IGW, give medium EC2 instance as small instance may not be able take the EMR bootstrap loads (not enough memory etc).

Comment: Alternatively, you can SSH into master node and keep monitoring cloud-init.log, EMR logs such as /mnt/var/log/bootstrap-actions/ and /mnt/var/log/instance-state/ especially. Then you would be able to catch an error realtime. Please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html.

Comment: @mon here is the log:

bootstrap-actions:
INFO i-062fab1a95f485684: new instance started
ERROR i-062fab1a95f485684: failed to start. bootstrap action 1 failed with non-zero exit code.

That's all. I am not sure what it means. Additionally, there is no custom bootstrap file.

Comment: Then your bootstrap is failing. If you have specified a bootstrap script, please make sure it runs. Please go through all the log files and find the place where an error is reported. If you have put multiple stuff in a bootstrap script (if you have), then please put nothing. Please focus on the master instance only.

Comment: Okay, I created a new cluster from the console with 1 master instance only and it worked! However, when I try to create another cluster let's say with 1 master and 2 core or 1 master 3 core 1 task instance, the same thing happens it just waiting on "starting" state and log says "failed to start. bootstrap action 1 failed with non-zero exit code." @mon